# Notes not synced to iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

I went to read notes on my iPhone - there were only 28 (using iCloud)
My Mac has 35 - those I had added recently are not there.

This has always worked in the past.
Any idea what is wrong (and how to fix it).

My iMac is running 12.6.2
My iPhone is upgraded to 16.2

I have never used iCloud Drive and only sync Contacts, Calendar & Notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into **System Settings**.  Select **AppleId**. Uncheck *Notes*. Wait a couple seconds and then check *Notes*

[image: Screenshot of System Settings to uncheck, then check Notes]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.